# Unable to add reference in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mysql-connector

I have a project in VS 2017 all was working well until I update Mysql connector and hence mysql.data reference.

As you can see in the picture, when I open the reference dialog box, only come up the new version of the referenceand when i try to select it and save, an error arises:

[image]

The error says: "Already exists a reference to 'MySql.Data' in the project"

The question is: How can I remove the older reference? It's not shown in the dialogbox and do not know where to find it.

Any help;

Comment: Did you check `Bin\Debug` folder and try removing it?

Comment: If you expand the `References`-tree in your project, you can remove it from there. If it was installed as a nuget-package, it is recommended that you use the nuget package installer to remove or update the package.

Comment: If `MySql.Data` reference installed from NuGet, remove the previous one with `Uninstall-Package MySql.Data -Force`, then `Install-Package MySql.Data -Version [new version number]`.

Comment: I just installed a package downloaded from MySQL website not inNuGet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a look at the Solution Explorer of your project:
[image]

And remove the reference by pressing delete or right click and Remove.
You can open the Solution Explorer by View -> Solution Explorer:

[image]

Or pressing `Ctrl + W, S`

Answer (score 0):

Weird! I use VS 2010 and was able to add reference more than once without this error popping up.

The References can be found in project structure in "Solution Explorer" . Just remove the old reference and add new. If you are unable to find the Solution explorer you can go to "view" tab and activate it.